# How to make current page item in nav menu different color.

Tags: css, wordpress, genesis

I am trying to make current page items in the sub-page nav menu of the below dev site a different color. By this I mean when you are on, for example, the page "Sample Page" here:

http://yamina.squareeyes.com.au/catalogue/sample-page/

I want the sub-menu item "Sample Page" to be the color #b8b041 same as a:hover items for this sub-menu.

I should point out I am using Wordpress, Genesis frame-work, a child theme and the plug-in "Genesis Subpages as Secondary Menu". While the menu behaves as I want when this plugin is deactivated, not so when it is activated.

Seeing as line 958 works for the hover I would have expected line 959 to also work but clearly I am a hack...

```
.genesis-nav-menu a:hover,
.genesis-nav-menu .current-menu-item > a  {
color: #B8B041; }
```

http://yamina.squareeyes.com.au/wp-content/themes/genesis-sample/style.css

Comment: Try classnames `current_page_item`, `current_page_parent` and `current_page_ancestor` alongside the `current-menu-item` class. Could you paste the HTML source that you're trying to apply your styles to?

Comment: Yeah current_page_item it was!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the following css

```
.nav-secondary .genesis-nav-menu a:hover,
.nav-secondary .genesis-nav-menu .current_page_item a{color: #B8B041;}
```